# Any proper module for leave management system?

Tags: nodes

I apologise if this is not the right place...
Is there any module for leave management system that used in any Intranet portal or any management system.

Anybody have an idea where to begin with? 
I have to add a fixed number for a maximum leave for a year and have to decrease the count per user on approval of any leave. How to add it with each user's profile.